# How to add custom appender in Log4j2 :

Tags: maven, log4j2

Hi I was trying to use appender available at https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/LOG4J2-431.

I tried to add these files in `log4j2` code and build using `maven` and then use `log4j2` jar but I am getting error `CALSS_NOT_FOUND`.

Please suggest am I missing some step while adding it to `log4j2` jar. Here is my log4j2.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The Jira ticket you're referring to is a proposal. The memory mapped file appender is still in the concept phase and has not been implemented yet. Patches are always welcome if you like this idea and have time to work on it.